# Startup a Camel Spring DSL route

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am somewhat of a novice working with the Camel ***Spring DSL*** Routes. My experience has been mostly with Java DSL.

I recently looked at a project that was based on Camel Spring DSL and noticed that the entire
project consisted of just the XML Routes and a few supporting classes for special Processors.
Nowhere could I found a Java class to actually **Start** the route(s) running. I was expecting to
find a class that started with something like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LocalAppRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(LocalAppRunner.class);
        springApplication.setBanner(new TraneBanner());
        springApplication.setAdditionalProfiles("local");
        springApplication.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.LOG);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
```

But evidently there is is no need for any class ( *that is overtly written as part of the project* )
to fire up the Route.

My guess is that the Route is started with something like  **mvn spring-boot:run**

Can anyone clarify if I am am correct in this assumption that Spring DSL does not require an overt
Java ( *or Groovy* ) class to fire up a route but can rely on just a mvn reference as indicated above.
( *of course the POM file would need the proper entries* )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the project in question is camel-spring project and not a camel-spring-boot project. Based on the [camel-archetype-spring](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-maven-archetypes.html) the startup method is hidden in the [org.apache.camel.spring.Main](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-3.20.2/components/camel-spring-main/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/Main.java#L94) class of camel-spring-main dependency.

By default camel-spring-main looks for spring xml configuration files from the `META-INF/spring/` folder. The application can be started with the [camel-maven-plugin](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-maven-plugin.html) using `mvn camel:run` command.

If you however want to run camel routes defined with xml with camel-spring-boot project you can place the xml files to path `src/main/resources/camel/` in your project. For more information you can look at the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html#_adding_xml_routes).

**Example file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- routes.xml -->
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="test">
        <from uri="timer://trigger?period=1000" />
        <log message="Hello from xml" />
    </route>
</routes>
```

The file should only contain the route definition as camel-spring-boot-starter handles creating and configuring CamelContext.

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer ....you state "..If you however want to run camel routes defined with xml with camel-spring-boot project..." ...would startup of the routes also be mvn camel:run or would it be mvn spring-boot:run ? I assume that in the case of XML DSL, an overt .java class is not needed ...just the XML Route itself ?

Comment: You can start camel-spring-boot project with the  `mvn spring-boot:run`.  The `camel-spring-boot-starter` dependency automatically creates, configures and starts up CamelContext. It also looks for RouteBuilder beans and xml route-definitions and adds them to the context.